# Elastic Beanstalk 504 Gateway Timeout Error - Django

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I recently completed the W3schools.com Django Tutorial. I followed it step by step. Everything works as expected locally. I also created and connected a PostgreSQL database on Amazon RDS to my app. Eventually I deployed the Django application to Elastic Beanstalk. Finally I visited the website and the homepage works, including 5 items added to the database during the tutorial which was migrated from the tutorial to the Amazon RDS. Unfortunately, neither the Django admin panel nor a simple subdirectory of the website are accessible. I get a 504 Gateway Time-out error. I don't know why. It is not clear from the logs what the issues might be. I am thinking it could possibly be a configuration file error or an incorrect value of settings.py on Django's side. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I want to point out that elasticbeanstalk.com/admin does work, but when I input the correct credentials, it also leads me to the 504.